# Overlapping an element from a belower z-index

Tags: css, overflow, overlap

I have some problems understanding an overlap of divs in Javascript.

See http://jsfiddle.net/CapKK/

As you can see the green box is wrapped by those two others. But as soon as I add a z-index to div1 (the red box) it doesn't work anymore.

Can someone explain that? Why does a z-index of 0 on div1 destroys this setup?

Comment: You may want to read up on how the stacking context is generated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context. In particular, the stacking context isn't formed unless the element is positioned with a z-index other than auto. Once it *is* formed though, the entire element (along with its children) follows the stacking order, which is why you get the green box overlapping the others when div1 has a z-index of 0.

Comment: Ok, I understand why it does what it does when z-index is set to 0 for div1. But it still doesn't explain why it behave that way with z-index auto set on div1. I modified the example a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/CapKK/1/ In what stacking order is div3 here? It is the only one that has z-index set, but behaves like all 3 were in the same stack order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

The div3 have a greater stack order that's why its on front.

If you add more elements to the page later, you have room to layer them in without having to adjust the z-index values of all the other elements. For example:

```
* 100 for my top-most element
* 0 for my middle element
* -100 for my bottom element
```

You can also give two elements the same z-index value. If these elements are stacked, they will display in the order they are written in the HTML, with the last element on top.

You can give each element you want layered a different z-index value. For example, if I have five different elements:

```
* element 1 — z-index of -25
* element 2 — z-index of 82
* element 3 — z-index not set
* element 4 — z-index of 10
* element 5 — z-index of -3
```

They will stack in the following order:

1. element 2
2. element 4
3. element 3
4. element 5
5. element 1

Comment: That's clear. It's more the strange thing that div2 can be wrapped by div1 and div3. As far as I know those are not in the same stack order.